# Android studio unable to install apk

Tags: android

I'm unable to install application from android studio. When i try to run the appliaction, all it says is:

> Waiting for device.
>   Target device: samsung...

So, I am able to select target device, but it all ends there.
Any ideas what should I do?

Comment: recheck your application android:targetSdkVersion and your mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you switched on the USB Debugging under Developer Options?  Also, check the Unknown Sources to install apps from sources other than Play Store.

Comment: I did. I was able to run the application last week at work. But today, I got at work and suddenly it just stopped working. I tried cleaning the project and building it again but no luck. I also tried restarting my phone.

Comment: Are you able to do 'adb shell' to the device?

Comment: I don't know. How can i do that?

Comment: From your terminal run $adb shell; see if it connects or show the output of $adb devices

Comment: it says that adb is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: 'adb' is located in your adt bundle at:  adt-bundle-****/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Never mind. I discovered the problem. My coworker changed some project settings without letting me know. Thanks anyway :)